# Method to update date in MySQL based on current time period?

Tags: mysql, sql

Let's say I have a MySQL Table with a single date column:

```
ID | dates
----------
1  | 2013-12-30
2  | 2013-12-30
3  | 2013-12-31
4  | 2013-01-04
5  | 2013-01-05
```

...

Basically I want to create a query that checks for the following: are any of the dates in the table prior to today (for this exampe let's assume it is 1-1-2014), if a date is found (in this case 1,2,3), update that date based on the following logic:

(day is today's actual number, so 01-01-2014 would be 1).

- If day < 4, update to the 5th of the current month
- If 4 >= day < 9, update to the 10th of the current month
- If 9 >= day < 14, update to the 15th of the current month
- If 14 >= day < 19, update to the 20th of the current month
- If 19  >= day < 24, update to the 25th of the current month
- If 24 >= day < 29, update to the 1st of the next month
- If day >= 29, update to the 5th of the next month

In my example table, after said query is run, the new table would look like the following:

```
ID | dates
----------
1  | 2014-01-05
2  | 2014-01-05
3  | 2014-01-05
4  | 2013-01-04
5  | 2013-01-05
```

I am trying to accomplish this without the use of a programming language like PHP (if possible).

Comment: Check your inequalities, they seem wrong/reversed.

Comment: @peter.petrov - you are correct. Sorry, fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this logic with MySQL's date functions.  The approach that I take for the current month is to use `makdedate()`, which relies on the day of the year.  Fortunately, there is a function to return this information.  The logic is to take the current date of the year, subtract the current date of the month, and add the day you want in the month.

```
update t
   set date = (case when day(now()) < 4 then makedate(year(now()), dayofyear(now()) - day(now()) + 5)
                    when day(now()) < 9 then makedate(year(now()), dayofyear(now()) - day(now()) + 10)
                    when day(now()) < 14 then makedate(year(now()), dayofyear(now()) - day(now()) + 15)
                    when day(now()) < 19 then makedate(year(now()), dayofyear(now()) - day(now()) + 20)
                    when day(now()) < 24 then makedate(year(now()), dayofyear(now()) - day(now()) + 25)
                    when day(now()) < 29 then makedate(year(now()), dayofyear(now()) - day(now()) + 30)
                    else date_add(last_day(now(), interval 5 day)
                end)                    
   where t.dates < now();
```

Comment: awesome - never knew about the makedate function. Thanks!